# Einstein's mass-energy equivalence

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

Einstein's wonder equation $E=m c^2$,if we take energy is proportional to the mass, we can put single constant to make that equivalent equation.

We all know that $\mathrm{constant}\cdot\mathrm{constant}=\mathrm{constant}$, since why do not we use $k=c\cdot c$ instead $c\cdot c$?

I have never seen an equation with square of a constant (if there are, please let me to know, for proportionality equations), why Einstein (deliberately?) left his equation with square of velocity of light?

oh, sorry, the universe made up of matter and radiation(I had red that some where), the matter can be converted into energy, the converse too, is there any proportionality between energy and mass?

Incidently, if we are living in velocity of light reference frame(c=1), can we distinguish energy and mass?

on other words, at that level, mass equal to energy or mass totally become energy?

since, energy particles(photons?) travels at velocity of light?

Comment: Hi just for another pov,  _Einstein (deliberately?) left his equation_   Actually, Lorentz is credited in many sources, for example **Einstein's Mistakes** as using this equation years before Einstein. Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [asking for the reasons for terminology/notation is off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/50583).

Comment: Is using $k=c.c$ not the same thing as using $c.c$? I strongly feel this is offtopic.

Comment: @ACuriousMind me too instantly. It's extremely vague...

Comment: With regards to the edits, isn't Einstein's "wonder equation" a *proportionality between energy and mass* that you request?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty, *plenty* and **plenty** of equations with constants under the different degrees.

The main reason for this: the $c^2$, $\hbar^2$ and other doesn't have any direct physical meaning; contrary the $c$, $\hbar$, $e$, various masses and other.

Answer (score 1):

einstein did not give e=mcc at first rather he had given  l=mvv where l is energy and v is velocity o f  light. e =mcc is written in this way to show the unique dependence of energy to the speed of light.